# Cannot Deploy Xamarin Forms iOS App on Real device for Debugging on Windows

Tags: xamarin.ios, iosdeployment

I am not able to deploy Xamarin iOS app on Real Device.
Here is my Visual Studio Details
[image]

Getting the Following Log in Output window
[image]

I have gone through every possible solution but no luck.

1. Creating New Certificate and Provisioning profle
2. Using Automatic Provisioning profile
3. Clearing all Cache

Nothing seems working

Comment: Open the project in Xcode and try from there will provide better error messages. You need the apple developer program membership ($99/year)

Comment: @BenButterworth i am using Windows Platform to deploy and debug iOS as well as Android app.
And i have a licensed Apple developer Program membership

Comment: How did you add your physical device to the provisioning profile? This is done automatically by Xcode on macOS. I'm not sure if it's even possible to build on Window for *iOS physical devices*. It's likely that you'd need a mac, but if you're lucky and I'm confused, maybe you don't. I don't use Xamarin Forms though. Edit: You need a macOS device to build for Xamarin.iOS

Comment: @BenButterworth Yes we can add physical Device to windows machine and deploy app ios app on it
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows)

Comment: Did you read the part on that page which says you **need** a network-accessible Mac set up with Apple's build tools, or *step 2*, which says `Set up Mac (Install Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac)`

Comment: @BenButterworth all this is taken care. i have deployed the Xamarin app previously on to real device, this is first time i am facing this issue.
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.DeveloperDiskImageService Error: 0 : Failed to download the Developer Disk image for iOS 14.7

Comment: Try to update Xcode to version 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

To build for Xamarin.iOS, you need **Xcode**, and therefore you need macOS. From [Xamarin.iOS Installation guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/):

> To build for Xamarin.iOS, the following are required:
>
> - the latest version of Visual Studio
> - the latest iOS SDK
> - the latest version of **Xcode**
> - the minimum version of **macOS** required by Xcode

Answer (score 0):

- You can use Automatic Provisioning、Manual Provisioning、Free
  Provisioning to deploy to real devices
- For more information, please refer to
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/

Comment: I used manual as well as Automatic provisioning but no luck
Error log showing the following error
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.DeveloperDiskImageService Error: 0 : Failed to download the Developer Disk image for iOS 14.7